batch script pass a variable to variable in txt file to use
I have a batch script that executes a job, and creates a log file for that job. The log file name is the date and time the job ran, e.g. C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv.
When the job is completed, send an email alert of job status e.g. 'Success' or 'Failed' to IT admin. sendmail.exe is used to send the email, and uses a txt file which contains the email 'To', 'From', 'Subject', and 'Body'. The email is sent to internal email recipients only.
In the batch script, I want to store the log filename in a variable, and pass the variable into a text file at a specific line location, or in a variable. How can this be done?
I have googled and applied some suggestions, however the variable name is not stored in the txt file at the specific location.
Batch script code:
:: send email of script results. 
if %JOB_RESULT% equ 0 (
  :: script is successful
  echo Success. send email 
  @echo off
  :: send email To email address 1
  sendmail.exe -t < C:\Temp\success_email_1.txt
   :: send email To email address 2
  sendmail.exe -t < C:\Temp\success_email_2.txt
  pause
  exit /b 0
) else (
  :: script failed
  echo Error. send email alert
  @echo off
  :: send email To email address 1
  sendmail.exe -t < C:\Temp\error_email_1.txt
  :: send email To email address 2
  sendmail.exe -t < C:\Temp\error_email_2.txt
  exit /b 1
)
pause

The contents of success_email_1.txt are:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: itadmin@company.com.au 
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams <name>

Log file name <Variable of log file name & date and time of job execution>


Also, at the moment the txt file can only store one email address.
How can I have multiple email addresses?
e.g. Ideally success_email.txt containing multiple 'To' email addresses:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: itadmin@company.com.au; 2ndEmailaddress@company.com.au, 3rdEmailaddress@company.com.au
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

When I add multiple 'To' email addresses it errors. It maybe related to syntax or spaces between the email addresses. ideally to have one txt file which stores and sends to multiple email addresses. As a workaround I used multiple txt files.

Issue 1:
Within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements), REM statements rather than the broken-label remark form (:: comment) should be used because labels terminate blocks, confusing cmd. :: is a broken label because you cannot reach :: with a goto, but it's a label nonetheless.
Issue 2:
Sendmail's -t option should provide the multiple-destination-address facility; `-t address1 address2 address3. Possibly semicolon-separators between addresses. (finding docco not so squeezy)
Issue 3: (minor,policy)
The date/time format ccyymmdd hhmmss is better from a sorting point-of-view. There are many examples of how to do this on SO - use the search facility near the top [batch] date format for example. Note that date-formatting is highly machine dependent.
Issue 4:
Possibly you could include the file data in the subject line (sendmail -u option, I believe)
If you want to vary the text in the message body, then there are plenty of examples on SO (repeat search sermon) - just set up a template file and replace a known string in that file (such as putthefilenamehere) with the filename as appropriate, creating a new file and then use that new file as the message text.

Several issues here...
Don't use :: for comments, always use rem commands. The reason is explained here
The simplest way to expand the value of a variable that is placed inside a text file is enclosing the variable name between exclamation marks and use a for /F command to show the file with Delayed Expansion Enabled:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize values for this example
set "name=Tests Name"
set "logFileName=C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv"

rem Send email of script results. 
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" input.txt') do echo/%%b) > output.txt
sendmail.exe -t < output.txt

input.txt:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: itadmin@company.com.au 
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams: "!name!"

Log file name: !logFileName!

output.txt:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: itadmin@company.com.au 
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams: "Tests Name"

Log file name: C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv

You can use the same trick to repeat the process with several email addresses replaced in TO variable:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize values for this example
set "name=Tests Name"
set "logFileName=C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv"

set "emails=itadmin@company.com.au 2ndEmailaddress@company.com.au 3rdEmailaddress@company.com.au"

rem Send email of script results. 
for %%e in (%emails%) do (
   set "TO=%%e"
   (for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" input.txt') do echo/%%b) > output.txt
   sendmail.exe -t < output.txt
)

input.txt:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: !TO!
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams: "!name!"

Log file name: !logFileName!

First output.txt:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: itadmin@company.com.au
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams: "Tests Name"

Log file name: C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv

Second output.txt:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: 2ndEmailaddress@company.com.au
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams: "Tests Name"

Log file name: C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv

Third output.txt:
From: name@company.com.au 
To: 3rdEmailaddress@company.com.au
Subject: email Alert - job completed OK

Files were downloaded and moved successfully to local folder on serverName & ip address, and moved to SharePoint folder - Teams: "Tests Name"

Log file name: C:\Temp\Logs\outputFile_Wed_02102024_114426_89.csv

You can even optimize your program further by removing the if %JOB_RESULT% equ 0 ( line/logic and selecting the appropriate file via an array element. For example, if %JOB_RESULT% is 0 when successful and 1 when failed, then you can initilize this array:
set "input[0]=success_email.txt"
set "input[1]=error_email.txt"

... and then replace the input.txt file by !input[%JOB_RESULT%]! in order to cover both cases with the same code.
You can read further details about array management in this answer
